# PHP how to split path to object attribute

Tags: php

I have source of data and it is like:

```
$sourceData = json_decode($sourceData);
```

OR

```
$sourceData = simplexml_load_string($sourceData);
```

but possibly it could be another type of source and the result is probably php object with path to attributes like this:

```
$sourceData->product->time[$x]->location->precipitation['value'];
```

and I would like to split the path like this:

```
$rootPath = $sourceData->product->time[$x];
$rest = ? 
/* probably something like '{$location}->{$precipitation}['value'] 
but I want the rest in one variable like 
$rest = 'location->precipitation['value'];
*/
```

so at the end I should load paths like or similar to:

```
$temperature = 'location->data->something->temperature['value'];'
$precipitation = 'location->xxx->yyy->precip['data'];'
```

and use like:

```
for($i)
{
   $temp = $root[$i]->temperature;
   $precip = $root[$i]->precipitation;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with dynamic paths (like "dot notation"), but I'd hold off with it and make sure I really need that. It might be slow and it's used in more generic situations - unknown variable paths that client will provide.

Cleaner way would be encapsulating each root subtree (`$data->product->time`) within object with methods that can reach deep inside and return what you want. For example:

```
class ProductProperties
{
    private $data;

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function temperature()
    {
        return $this->data->location->something->temperature['value'];
    }

    //...
}
```

Then creating instance and calling it within loop (or separate loops):

```
foreach ($sourceData as $root) {
    $properties = new ProductProperties($root);
    $temp = $properties->temperature();
}
```